# Using jq in Gitlab CI yaml

Tags: shell, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, jq

I'm having a json file sample.json. Below is the snippet from the sample.json -

```
{
"AddOnModules": {
        "Description": "add on modules",
        "Type": "Array",
        "AllowedValues": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
        ],
        "value": []
    }
}
```

I'm trying to provide value to AddOnModules through git ci variable (parameter-value) at runtime while running the pipeline. The following is the snippet of the pipeline -

```
stages: 
  - deploy
  
# Job to deploy for development  
dev-deploy:

  variables:

  before_script:
    - apk add jq
    
  image: python:3.7.4-alpine3.9
  script:
    - tmp=$(mktemp)
    - jq -r --arg add_on_modules "$add_on_modules" '.AddOnModules.value  |= .+ [$add_on_modules] ' sample.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" sample.json
    - cat sample.json
  stage: deploy
  tags: 
    - docker
    - linux
  only:
    variables:
        - $stage =~ /^deploy$/ && $deployment_mode =~ /^dev$/
```

I'm giving the value of variable add_on_modules as "a","b" through git ci while running the pipeline. On performing cat sample.json, it's observed to be -

```
{
    "AddOnModules": {
            "Description": "add on modules",
            "Type": "Array",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "a",
                "b",
                "c"
            ],
            "value": [ "\"a\",\"b\""]
        }
 }
```

The extra double quotes are getting the prepended and appended while the existing ones are escaped.
I want output something like -

```
{
        "AddOnModules": {
                "Description": "add on modules",
                "Type": "Array",
                "AllowedValues": [
                    "a",
                    "b",
                    "c"
                ],
                "value": ["a","b"]
            }
}
```

Looks like I'm missing something with jq -

```
- jq -r --arg add_on_modules "$add_on_modules" '.AddOnModules.value  |= .+ [$add_on_modules] ' sample.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" sample.json
```

Tried with -r/--raw-output flag with jq but no success. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

This is how I'm running the pipeline -

[Pipeline run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGL6d.png)

Comment: Tried your snippet via bash, looks good to me. Setting add_on_module=a,b gives the right answer. So are you sure your CI is really setting up the variable ?

Comment: I mean, I'm not setting up add_on_module="a","b" inside the job. I'm passing through the parameter-value combination while running the pipeline at runtime. I've edited the post and attached the image. Please refer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If $add_on_modules is `["a","b"]`

If you can set add_on_modules to the textual representation of a JSON array, then you would use `--argjson`, like so:

```
add_on_modules='["a","b"]'
jq -r --argjson add_on_modules "$add_on_modules" '
 .AddOnModules.value  += $add_on_modules
' sample.json
```

#### If $add_on_modules is the string `"a","b"`

```
add_on_modules='"a","b"'
jq -r --arg add_on_modules "$add_on_modules" '
  .AddOnModules.value  += ($add_on_modules|split(",")|map(fromjson)) 
  ' sample.json
```

Comment: I'm not setting up add_on_modules inside the job. I'm passing through the parameter-value combination while running the pipeline at runtime. I've edited the post and attached the image. Please refer that. Even if I pass ["a","b"] while running the pipeline, it simply gives array and string cannot be added error since .AddOnModules.value has a default value of empty array([]) in sample.json